# Unwrap angle to have continuous phase

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, complex-numbers, phase

Let's say I have an array of phases similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
phase = np.linspace(0., 100., 1000) % np.pi
plt.plot(phase)
plt.show()
```

(with many discontinuities like this)

[image]

**How to get an array of more "continuous" phases from it?**

Of course, I already tried with [`np.unwrap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html):

```
plt.plot(np.unwrap(phase))
```

or

```
plt.plot(np.unwrap(phase),discont=0.1)
```

but it stays exactly similar:

[image]

What I expected was an unwrapping like this:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to keep your original phase with pi-periodicity, you should first double it, unwrap it, then divide it by two:

`plt.plot(np.unwrap(2 * phase) / 2)`

Comment: Stupid question: why are the doubling and halving required? Does it depend on the parsed value of "discont" ?

Answer (score 4):

My problem came from that fact I had a 2D array `(n,1)` (without noticing it) in my real code, instead of a 1D array of length `n`. Then the parameter `axis`:

```
np.unwrap(phase, axis=0)
```

solved it.

The other answers are still useful because of `2 pi` vs. `pi` question.

Answer (score 2):

From the doc of `np.unwrap`:

> Unwrap radian phase `p` by changing absolute jumps greater than
>   `discont` to their 2*pi complement along the given axis.

But the 2*pi complement of all the elements in your vector are the values themselves since no value is every > 2*pi.

Try this:

```
phase = np.linspace(0., 20., 1000) % 2*np.pi

plt.figure()

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(phase)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(np.unwrap(phase))
```

[image]