# Python: How to unwrap circular data to remove discontinuities?

Tags: python, numpy, grid, interpolation, word-wrap

I have a grid of circular data, e.g. the data is given by its angle from `0` to `π`. Within this data, I have another smaller grid.

This might look like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to interpolate the black data on the red dots. Therefore I'm using `scipy.interpolate.griddata`. This will give me the following result:

[image]

As you see, there is a discontinuity when the angle changes from 'almost `0`' to 'almost `π`'.

To remove that, I tried to unwrap the data before interpolation. According to this answer [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52294869/3401634). And I get this (better) result, but surprisingly, there is a new disconituity on the right that I don't understand.

[image]

So my question is: How to use `np.unwrap` to get a continous interpolation? Or is there a better way to do so?

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

ax = plt.subplot()
ax.set_aspect(1)

# Simulate some given data.
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10, 10, 20), np.linspace(-10, 10, 20))
phi = np.arctan2(y, x) % (2 * np.pi)
data = np.arctan2(np.cos(phi), np.sin(phi)) % np.pi

# Plot data.
u = np.cos(data)
v = np.sin(data)
ax.quiver(x, y, u, v, headlength=0.01, headaxislength=0, pivot='middle', units='xy')

# Create a smaller grid within.
x1, y1 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-6, 5, 20), np.linspace(-4, 8, 25))
# ax.plot(x1, y1, '.', color='red', markersize=2)

# Prepare data.
data = np.unwrap(2 * data) / 2

# Interpolate data on grid.
interpolation = griddata((x.flatten(), y.flatten()), data.flatten(), (x1.flatten(), y1.flatten()))

# Plot interpolated data.
u1 = np.cos(interpolation)
v1 = np.sin(interpolation)
ax.quiver(x1, y1, u1, v1, headlength=0.01, headaxislength=0, pivot='middle', units='xy',
          scale=3, width=0.03, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Comment: well, unwrap only works along one dimension. The second discontinuity has exactly the same nature. You could probably unwrap and interpolate along one dimension, and then along another. I'll try to add code later

Comment: No, the second one has not exactly the same nature. Because: While the first one is symetrically along the whole y-axis (i.e. `y < 0` and `y > 0`), the second one is completely right for `x < 0` but not for `x > 0`. This I don't understand at all. Why it does not give a discontinuity along the whole x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To operate correctly on [circular quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities), convert the angles to complex numbers before calling `griddata` and back to angles afterwards:

```
c=np.exp(2j*data)  # 0,pi -> 1
# …
a=np.angle(interpolation)/2
```

The factors of 2 spread your [0,π) out to the whole circle and back again.  Note that the normalization implicit in the call to `angle` will be very sensitive to input that changes too much within one “grid cell” of the input data.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much! :)